# Getting 409 Error unable to resolve how can i solve

Tags: android, exception, error-handling, runtime-error, android-volley

> E/Volley: [19528] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 409 for http://13.232.142.23:3000/api/register

I have some code to make an alert if user is already register and if otp is incorrect but while registering,the alert is not appearing if entering otp is incorrect or if user is already registered. What is the issue? i am unable to get it.

//registerUser(phone,otp,fullname,email,  password, device_id );

```
    private void registerUser(final String phone,final String otp,final String fullname,final String email,  final String password, final String device_id )
    {

        Log.e(TAG, "otp12 " +otp11);

        String tag_string_req = "req_register";



        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");



        params.put("phone",phone);
        params.put("otp",otp);
        params.put("fullname", fullname);
        params.put("email",email);


        params.put("password",password);

        params.put("device_id", device_id);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.Base_Url+AppConfig.App_api+AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()

 {

                  @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response1) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response1.toString());


                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response1));
                    String response = jObj.getString("code");
                    String status =jObj.getString("status");
                    String message= jObj.getString("message");

                    Log.e(TAG, "r2222" + response);
                    Log.e(TAG, "status1: " + status);
                    Log.e(TAG,"Message"+message);
                    if (status!=null && status.equals("true")) {

                        launchAgeScreen();

                        Log.e(TAG, "123" + fullname);
                        Log.e(TAG, "status: " + status);
                        Log.e(TAG, "paswword: " + password);

                        Log.e(TAG, "response2163123: " + response);

                    }else if (status!=null && message.equals("user is already register"))
                    {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Registration Error");
                        builder.setMessage("You have already registered with FeeDeposit. Please click Okay to Login");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivityWithoutSharedPreference.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();

                    }


                    else if (status!=null && message.equals("invalid otp"))
                    {

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme).create();

                        // Setting Dialog Title
                        alertDialog.setTitle("OTP ");

                        // Setting Dialog Message
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Invalid OTP");

                        // Setting Icon to Dialog
                        //  alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

                        // Setting OK Button
                        alertDialog.setButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                        alertDialog.show();

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme).create();

                    // Setting Dialog Title
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Network/Connection Error");

                    // Setting Dialog Message
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Internet Connection is poor OR The Server is taking too long to respond.Please try again later.Thank you.");

                    // Setting Icon to Dialog
                    //  alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

                    // Setting OK Button
                    alertDialog.setButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    // Showing Alert Message
                    alertDialog.show();
                   // Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    /*Toast.makeText(context,
                            context.getString(R.string.error_network_timeout),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                } /*else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    //TODO
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    //TODO
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    //TODO
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    //TODO
                }
*/



            }
        }) /*{

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                // Posting params to register url

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");



                params.put("phone",phone);
                params.put("otp",otp);
                params.put("fullname", fullname);
                params.put("email",email);


                params.put("password",password);

                params.put("device_id", device_id);




                return params;
            }

        }*/;






        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN
                && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            try {
                ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                // Indicates that Google Play services is out of date, disabled, etc.
                // Prompt the user to install/update/enable Google Play services.
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), getApplicationContext());
                // Notify the SyncManager that a soft error occurred.
                //final SyncResult syncResult = null;
                //syncResult.stats.numIOExceptions++;

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sync", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                // Indicates a non-recoverable error; the ProviderInstaller is not able
                // to install an up-to-date Provider.
                // Notify the SyncManager that a hard error occurred.
                //syncResult.stats.numAuthExceptions++;
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sync12", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            HttpStack stack = null;
            try {
                stack = new HurlStack(null, new TLSSocketFactory());
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Your Wrapper Class", "Could not create new stack for TLS v1.2");
                stack = new HurlStack();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Your Wrapper Class", "Could not create new stack for TLS v1.2");
                stack = new HurlStack();
            }

             Appcontrol.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_string_req);
           // AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(),stack);

            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), stack);
        } else {

            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            //AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
        }

        Appcontrol.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_string_req);




        // Adding request to request queue
      //
        //
        //
        //
        //
        //AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```